# PulseAudio switching default sink shortly after boot

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 with bspwm. On each boot, I have to re-specify my sink with `pactl set-default-sink 0` to get HDMI sound working.

Here's the list of my sinks:

```bash
$ pacmd list-sinks | grep -e 'name:' -e 'index:'
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.hdmi-stereo>
  * index: 1
    name: <alsa_output.usb-Generic_USB_Audio-00.iec958-stereo>
```

I have tried putting the `pactl set-default-sink 0` command in my `.bspwmrc` but it doesn't produce the same result as running it once OS has fully booted.

I have also tried editing `/etc/pulse/default.pa` and adding:

```
set-default-sink 0
```

or

```
set-default-sink alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.hdmi-stereo
```

These manage to initially set the correct sink, but revert back to the wrong one within a few seconds once OS is loaded.

If I had to guess, this is probably some power saving issue, or some service rewriting the defaults. Any thoughts?

Comment: I believe the user can also have pulse audio settings which are loaded upon login, e.g. in `/home/$USER/.config/pulse` and `/home/$USER/pulse` but also in `gsettings`. Could this be the reason why the setting is changed? (Perhaps try to log in with a different, "clean" user.)

Comment: This is a clean new install. I don't have `~/pulse` but do have `~/.config/pulse` and files in there seems to have been generated on boot and on volume change, etc. Also opening `gnome-control-center` for sound crashes, so can't really change `gsettings` either.

Answer (score 0):

I do not like workarounds but here is one that works (util I find a better solution): Add the `pactl set default sink` command in startup applications.

- Open the application "Startup Applications"
- Click on "Add"
- Give your startup item a name
- Add:

  ```
  pactl set-default-sink 'Your-Device-Name'
  ```
- Click on "Add".

Your default audio device will be set on each boot and as such be persistent. If you want to change the default device simply edit the device name in startup applications command.